# How can I get an InstallShield Package to install as the SYSTEM user, or from SCCM?

Tags: sccm, windows-installer

There is a piece of software that I am trying to package that uses an InstallShield installer. I have tried the `/r` and get the `C:\Windows\setup.iss` file, and call the package via

```
 start "" /wait %~dp0setup.exe /s /SMS /f1"%~dp0setup.iss"
```

From a batch file. All the files are placed in a WinRAR sfx and extract to the C:\Temp\ folder.

This setup works fine when run as admin, however it will not run when deployed from SCCM. I have narrowed this down to the fact that SCCM runs it packages under the SYSTEM account. I used psexec to reproduce the issue, running the exe with

```
psexec \\localhost -s -i -h \\path\to\setup.exe
```

and It starts off okay, but right when it starts to install it errors out with a `-3 The system cannot find the path specified` error. I've used procmon but I can't find out what path its looking for and thus why it's not available to the system account.

From google I've seen other environments having this problem with other InstallShield packages, but I haven't seen a definitive problem Identified and thus no workaround or solution.

Comment: you could temporarily turn on file auditing to see whats going on.

Comment: Does System have access to \\path\to\setup.exe?  Or is it failing father along?

Comment: @KatherineVillyard farther along. I was actually able to find the msi and run it as system successfully, I didn't get a chance to post my answer yet. But now I've run into another issue: The program has to be run as admin (Windows elevated mode) on 1st use, if not, it crashes. (Vendor actually recommends the program is always run under a privileged account, not gonna happen)

Comment: @MDMoore313 I just hate software like this!

Answer (score 1):

I too am having a problem with an installshield installer for Pixelogic Sculptris.

The problem lies with the way SCCM uses the SYSTEM account whenever it runs as when "run with administrative rights" is set. That's why running the batch file I have from the cached folder (which points to the iss file) as myself and "run as admin" works, but initiating the program from within Advertised Programs does not.

If I set the program to run with user's rights, there is no problem.

Unfortunately some environments dont allow regular user accounts to be admins. I wish there was a way around this issue.

Comment: I think I missed it. Was there an actual answer here?